# Making POST request from ReactJS app built on WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, reactjs

I'm building a ReactJS app on top of a WordPress backend.  The React App is running on the same domain, embedded in the WordPress site.  Most of the tutorials I've been following cover how to get data from WordPress to React.  I've been successful at this, but need to figure out how to submit data from my React app to WordPress (preferably via the REST API).

This will be a custom admin page for logged in editors, either available in the admin panel or from the front-end.

As an example to create a post, I'm naively trying the following function:

```
  saveGrid() {
    const url = "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
    const body = JSON.stringify({
      "title":"internet",
      "content":"teapot"
    });

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body:body

    });
  }
```

I get back a 401 unauthorized response.  What is the easiest way to authorize myself for a POST submission (secure solution preferred)?

Comment: It looks like I could use oAuth, but that seems unnecessary, because I'm not really a third party application.  How do I communicate from WordPress to React back to Wordpress that I am a logged in editor?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're on the right track.

A quick read of this: https://apppresser.com/wp-api-post-submission/
shows me that all you're missing is a "nonce" in order for the WP API to recognise and validate your request successfully.

In the guide above, the dev created a JS written in JQuery that sends XHR/AJAX requests to the WP API and in their plugin.php they enqueue and localize the script with some variables from WP to help with the request inside the JS.

The takeaway here is that they used `wp_create_nonce('wp_rest')`and assigned this to a localized variable `nonce` so they could easily reference that later inside the JS and assign `nonce` to their `X-WP-Nonce` header inside the request!

If you look into this further you might find a suitable alternative for you that will work as I'm not entirely sure how you're loading your JSX files but this guide may come in handy for you to enqueue your JSX scripts/files: http://blog.milandinic.com/2015/12/01/using-react-jsx-in-wordpress/

**More information**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: That's the exact article I was starting to work from.  Good to know I'm on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, let us know if you have any success creating and using the nonce and if that resolves your 401 issue :)

Comment: Getting closer.  I generated the nonce using the method in apppresser tutorial.  Then I set it to a window variable so React could see it.  But now, I'm getting a 403 forbidden error saying that my nonce token doesn't match my cookie.  I'm looking into this now.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that my response header doesn't contain a cookie attribute.  I'm working on an alternate fix using a form submitting through admin-post.php and the post request that generates has a cookie attribute.

Comment: Interesting... would be good to see if you can get it to work eventually

Comment: I'm giving up for the time being.  I've got it working for my needs using admin-post.php instead of the API, which is fine because I'm doing all my submissions from the admin panel anyways so I don't need verification.

Comment: "It is important to keep in mind that this authentication method relies on WordPress cookies. As a result, this method is only applicable when the REST API is used inside of WordPress and the current user is logged in. In addition, the current user must have the appropriate capability to perform the action being performed."

Not sure if this helps you at all, but I thought I might share anyway?

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by, instead of having a straight post request from React, using a Jquery AJAX submission outside of React that uses data from a form inside React.  This caused the request to contain the necessary cookies (I don't understand exactly why this is the case)